# Why exactly do I need an explicit upcast when implementing QueryInterface() in an object with multiple interfaces()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, multiple-inheritance

Assume I have a class implementing two or more COM interfaces:

```
class CMyClass : public IInterface1, public IInterface2 {
};
```

Almost every document I saw suggests that when I implement QueryInterface() for IUnknown I explicitly upcast *this* pointer to one of the interfaces:

```
if( iid == __uuidof( IUnknown ) ) {
     *ppv = static_cast<IInterface1>( this );
     //call Addref(), return S_OK
}
```

The question is why can't I just copy *this*?

```
if( iid == __uuidof( IUnknown ) ) {
     *ppv = this;
     //call Addref(), return S_OK
}
```

The documents usually say that if I do the latter I will violate the requirement that any call to QueryInterface() on the same object must return exactly the same value.

I don't quite get that. Do they mean that if I QI() for IInterface2 and call QueryInterface() through that pointer C++ will pass *this* slightly different from if I QI() for IInterface2 because C++ will each time make *this* point to a subobject?

Comment: void** as usual in QueryInterface() samples.

Comment: So does: C* c = static_cast< C* >(this); guarantee a pointer to the correct sub-class? Or do I have to use dynamic_cast?

Comment: static_cast is enough if you cast to a base class - the compiler has enough data to do all the necessary adjustments during compile time. The compiler will refuse to do the static_cast to a derived class, but a dynamic_cast still could be successful.

Comment: Based on what do you suggest that `*ppv = this` will point to the base? I can't find anything in the Standard that would confirm that. Can you?

Comment: `*ppv = static_cast<IInterface1>( this );` even this statement lead to undefined behavior, because the Standard is not guarantee pointer-inconvertibility when class has non-standard layout (i.e. you return the pointer to `IInterface1`, not to `IUnknown`, there is only assumption that it will be the same). And `CMyClass` is a non-standard layout class for many reasons. I will be glad you share your current knowledge on this matter, after all 10 years have passed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that `*ppv` is usually a `void*` - directly assigning `this` to it will simply take the existing `this` pointer and give `*ppv` the value of it (since all pointers can be cast to `void*`).

This is not a problem with single inheritance because with single inheritance the base pointer is always the same for all classes (because the vtable is just extended for the derived classes).

However - for multiple inheritance you actually end up with multiple base pointers, depending on which 'view' of the class you're talking about!  The reason for this is that with multiple inheritance you can't just extend the vtable - you need multiple vtables depending on which branch you're talking about.

So you need to cast the `this` pointer to make sure that the compiler puts the correct base pointer (for the correct vtable) into `*ppv`.

Here's an example of single inheritance:

```
class A {
  virtual void fa0();
  virtual void fa1();
  int a0;
};

class B : public A {
  virtual void fb0();
  virtual void fb1();
  int b0;
};
```

vtable for A:

```
[0] fa0
[1] fa1
```

vtable for B:

```
[0] fa0
[1] fa1
[2] fb0
[3] fb1
```

Note that if you have the `B` vtable and you treat it like an `A` vtable it just works - the offsets for the members of `A` are exactly what you would expect.

Here's an example using multiple inheritance (using definitions of `A` and `B` from above) (note: just an example - implementations may vary):

```
class C {
  virtual void fc0();
  virtual void fc1();
  int c0;
};

class D : public B, public C {
  virtual void fd0();
  virtual void fd1();
  int d0;
};
```

vtable for C:

```
[0] fc0
[1] fc1
```

vtable for D:

```
@A:
[0] fa0
[1] fa1
[2] fb0
[3] fb1
[4] fd0
[5] fd1

@C:
[0] fc0
[1] fc1
[2] fd0
[3] fd1
```

And the actual memory layout for `D`:

```
[0] @A vtable
[1] a0
[2] b0
[3] @C vtable
[4] c0
[5] d0
```

Note that if you treat a `D` vtable as an `A` it will work (this is coincidence - you can't rely on it).  However - if you treat a `D` vtable as a `C` when you call `c0` (which the compiler expects in slot 0 of the vtable) you'll suddenly be calling `a0`!

When you call `c0` on a `D` what the compiler does is it actually passes a fake `this` pointer which has a vtable which looks the way it should for a `C`.

So when you call a `C` function on `D` it needs to adjust the vtable to point to the middle of the `D` object (at the `@C` vtable) before calling the function.

Comment: Does "depending on which view" boil down to "what type pointer is used to call QueryInterface()"?

Comment: Basically yes - the caller is expecting an object back which has a vtable layout exactly like what they're expecting.  However - since they're just passing a `void**` there is no compiler enforced type safety (or implicit casting).

Comment: Interesting, however I suppose there are actually 2 _vpointers in a D instance something like `@a0 A B @c0 C D` where A, B, C and D materialize the actual attributes of each class. I would appreciate if you had more detailed explanation of the actual memory layout (for a given compiler) when MI is involved.

Comment: @Matthiue M. - correct - there would be 2 vtables in a `D` instance.  I updated the description a little to include an example memory layout for `D`.  A whiteboard would be much better for this... :)

Answer (score 8):

You're doing COM programming, so there are a few things to recall about your code before looking at why `QueryInterface` is implemented the way it is.

1. Both `IInterface1` and `IInterface2` descend from `IUnknown`, and let's assume neither is a descendant of the other.
2. When something calls `QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, (void**)&intf)` on your object, `intf` will be declared as type `IUnknown*`.
3. There are multiple "views" of your object — interface pointers — and `QueryInterface` could be called through any one of them.

Because point #3, the value of `this` in your `QueryInterface` definition can vary. Call the function via an `IInterface1` pointer, and `this` will have a different value than it would if it were called via an `IInterface2` pointer. In either case, `this` will hold a valid pointer of type `IUnknown*` because of point #1, so if you simply assign `*ppv = this`, the caller will be happy, *from a C++ point of view*. You'll have stored a value of type `IUnknown*` into a variable of that same type (see point #2), so everything's fine.

However, *COM has stronger rules than ordinary C++*. In particular, it requires that any request for the `IUnknown` interface of an object must return the same pointer, no matter which "view" of that object was used to invoke the query. Therefore, it's not sufficient for your object to always assign mere `this` into `*ppv`. Sometimes callers would get the `IInterface1` version, and sometimes they'd get the `IInterface2` version. A proper COM implementation needs to make sure it returns consistent results. It will commonly have an `if`-`else` ladder checking for all supported interfaces, but one of the conditions will check for two interfaces instead of just one, the second being `IUnknown`:

```
if (iid == IID_IUnknown || iid == IID_IInterface1) {
  *ppv = static_cast<IInterface1*>(this);
} else if (iid == IID_IInterface2) {
  *ppv = static_cast<IInterface2*>(this);
} else {
  *ppv = NULL;
  return E_NOINTERFACE;
}
AddRef();
return S_OK;
```

It doesn't matter which interface the `IUnknown` check is grouped with as long as the grouping doesn't change while the object still exists, but you'd really have to go out of your way to make that happen.

Comment: I think you are wrong. `This` will always be the same, because all methods are virtual and an actual implementation of pure virtual `QueryInterface` belongs to the most derived class (which is the object from COM perspective).

Comment: It could differ in the case where methods of the base class is not virtual and the base class has its own implementation where its `this` used. Please, compile and check `this` addresses in the mentioned scenarios, because if I'm right, your answer is misleading.