# Is there any reason against directly calling AddRef() inside QueryInterface() implementation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, interop, com-interop

When implementing `IUnknown::QueryInterface()` in C++ there're several caveats with pointers manipulation. For example, when the class implements several interfaces (multiple inheritance) [explicit upcasts are necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742848/why-exactly-do-i-need-an-explicit-upcast-when-implementing-queryinterface-in-an):

```
class CMyClass : public IInterface1, public IInterface2 { 
}; 

//inside CMyClass::QueryInterface():
if( iid == __uuidof( IUnknown ) ) { 
     *ppv = static_cast<IInterface1*>( this ); // upcast in order to properly adjust the pointer
     //call Addref(), return S_OK 
}
```

The reason for upcast is quite clear in multiple inheritance scenarios. However every here and there I also see the following:

```
static_cast<IUnknown*>( *ppv )->AddRef();
```

instead of simply invoking `AddRef()` from inside `QueryInterface()` implementation.

Is there any reason I should do the cast of the value previously copied into `ppv` instead of just calling `AddRef()` on the current object?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the definition of IUnknown class?

Comment: @hype: Sure. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddRef` is pure virtual in `IUnknown`, and none of the other interfaces implement it, so the only implementation in your program is the one you write in `CMyClass`. That one method overrides *both* `IInterface1::AddRef` and `IInterface2::AddRef`. `IUnknown` doesn't have any data members (such as a reference count), so the diamond problem doesn't cause your class to be susceptible to a problem such as different calls to `AddRef` acting on different data in the same class.

Calls to `this->AddRef()` are going to be routed to the same place as `static_cast<IUnknown*>(*ppv)->AddRef()`. I see no reason for the more verbose style.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the verbose syntax probably lies in the fact that not only `this` might be returned in `ppv`, which is easy to overlook in a longer `if-else-if`. An example from Don Box's Essential COM:

```
STDMETHODIMP Car::IternalQueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv) {
    if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
        *ppv = static_cast<IUnknown*>(&m_innerUnknown);
    else if (riid == IID_IVehicle)
        *ppv = static_cast<IVehicle*>(this);
    else if (riid == IID_ICar)
        *ppv = static_cast<ICar*>(this);
    else
        return (*ppv = 0), E_NOINTERFACE;
    ((IUnknown*)*ppv)->AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}
```