# Is there any case when dynamic_cast should be used in the QueryInterface implementation?

Tags: c++, com, casting, multiple-inheritance

The typical way of implementing `IUnknown::QueryInterface()` is the following: use a chain of `if-else-if` for each supported interface id and do the following:

```
if( iid == __uuidof( IInterfaceN ) ) {
   *ppv = static_cast<IInterfaceN>( this );
   //call Addref(), return S_OK
}
```

Now `static_cast` [is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1742848/57428) here for proper pointer adjustment in multiple inheritance scenario.

Once in a while I see implementations that instead use `dynamic_cast`. IMO that's a waste of time - result will be the same, it'll just take longer and make the implementation overengineered.

Is there any case when using `dynamic_cast` is indeed necessary for casting `this` pointer before copying it into `void**` parameter of `IUnknown::QueryInterface()` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be necessary in those implementations of `QueryInterface` where the "supported interface ids" aren't known. E.g. if you decide to implement `QueryInterface` in a base class, and not override it for every derived class.

A case where this would happen is the situation where you have a lot of similar types, where "similar" means "implementing many of the same interfaces". I.e. you have object types `Derived1`... `DerivedN` which all implement some subset of `Interface1`...`InterfaceM`.

This could be the case for a game engine where game entities all implement a subset of `IMoveable`, `IScriptable`, `IFactory`, `IShoots`, `IPlayerControlled`, `IStealthy`, `ISensor`, etcetera. Of course, by COM rules you must be able to call `IFactory::QueryInterface` and get an `IMovable*` if and only if the factory also implements `IMovable`.

How are you going to implement all those `QueryInterface` methods? It's easiest to insert an `GameObject` base class between `IUnknown` and `IFactory`, and implement `GameObject::QueryInterface` using `dynamic_cast` checks. In this way, you need only one implementation, instead of one per interface of a concrete type.

Comment: Emm... Could you please provide some simplest example of such hierarchy?

Comment: Assume a `Base` and a set of `Derived1`...`DerivedN` classes, where the `Derived` classes each implement a random subset of `Interface1`...`InterfaceM`. In `Base::QueryInterface`, you'd check if `this` can be `dynamic_cast` to the demanded interface.

Comment: Okay, I see and it'a a valid example, although overengineered a bit. Could you please include it into the answer?

Answer (score 1):

`QueryInterface()` is in fact an implementation of a "dynamic cast" operator. Basing the implementation on top of another implementation that requires another variant of the same metadata (inheritance tree) makes no real sense.

A good compiler should be able to remap this into a `static_cast`.

Comment: would you please give a concrete example?