# Where does idea that "inheritance is to be avoided" originate from?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, inheritance

Recently we discussed a defect [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4884847/57428) and one of the parties said something like "yes, that's why books say that *inheritance should be avoided*.

I've been using inheritance for years and find it very useful and convenient in many design cases. Also I'm sure that the person arguing at the very least misunderstood what those "books say".

Is there really an idea that inheritance is kind of bad and should be avoided? Where does it originate and where can I learn more?

Comment: Well, I don't know but I prefer inheritance myself.

Comment: @Tuzo: Does it all boil down to "composition versus inheritance"?

Comment: At the very least I think it's a big part of it (all answers mention it). Although I must admit that intellectually I really love the conceptual elegance of inheritance. ("Why don't I marry it!?" :) )

Comment: See [Prefer composition over inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) for some more thoughts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what he might have meant is that inheritance can be overused, even in cases where composition would be a better solution. This is discussed in several books, e.g.

- [Effective Java 2nd Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Item 16: **Favor composition over inheritance**

> Inheritance is a powerful way to achieve code reuse, but it is not always the best
>   tool for the job. Used inappropriately, it leads to fragile software. It is safe to use
>   inheritance within a package, where the subclass and the superclass implementations
>   are under the control of the same programmers. It is also safe to use inheritance
>   when extending classes specifically designed and documented for extension
>   (Item 17). Inheriting from ordinary concrete classes across package boundaries,
>   however, is dangerous. As a reminder, this book uses the word “inheritance” to
>   mean implementation inheritance (when one class extends another). The problems
>   discussed in this item do not apply to interface inheritance (when a class implements
>   an interface or where one interface extends another).
>
> **Unlike method invocation, inheritance violates encapsulation** [Snyder86].
>   In other words, a subclass depends on the implementation details of its superclass
>   for its proper function. The superclass’s implementation may change from release
>   to release, and if it does, the subclass may break, even though its code has not
>   been touched. As a consequence, a subclass must evolve in tandem with its superclass,
>   unless the superclass’s authors have designed and documented it specifically
>   for the purpose of being extended.

- [Effective C++ 3rd Edition](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) has several items related to this:

  - Item 32: Make sure public inheritance models "is-a."
  - Item 34: Differentiate between inheritance of interface and inheritance of implementation
  - Item 38: Model "has-a" or "is-implemented-in-terms-of" through composition

Comment: See also "Head First Design Patterns".

Answer (score 3):

Not to be avoided every time, but it hinders flexibility wherever you are stuck with a defined set of operations from a superclass. The basic design idea is "leave to inheritance the fixed parts and inject the parts subject to change".

In [Head First Desing Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126) there is a good example.

Say you decide to model ducks with a base class which implements fly(). Say that you have a RubberDuck, who can't fly, of course. You override fly() with a method that does nothing. But then some day you add DecoyDuck and forget to override fly() and you get a mess. It would have been better to build the DecoyDuck injecting the desired behaviour (composition over inheritance).

Comment: can you really say that a rubber duck is a duck since it doesnt fly like a duck ?  if you can, is fly()) really fit for inclusion in the base class since it is not shared by all which is duck ....

Comment: exactly; inheritance is not fit to solve this kind of problem: if you say "yes, rubber duck is a duck" you have to override fly() in every subclass; if you say "no" you have to copy it everywhere

Comment: I agree with you in principle but I find the example less than convincing. I think the issue is that the abstraction of RubberDuck is not correct. If you were to look at a duck and a rubber duck and tried to classify them most people would say that a duck is an animal (or bird) while a rubber duck is a *toy* that happens to looks like a duck.

Comment: Oh, the perils of the leaky abstractions (which are far worse than the inheritance vs composition problem). It the programmer doesn't know what a duck is (in his context), then neither inheritance nor composition can help. +1 for highlighting that problem

Answer (score 2):

Good coding practice in C++ prefers composition through aggregation. cf. ["C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, And Best Practices" by Sutter/Alexandrescu](http://www.amazon.fr/Coding-Standards-Rules-Guidelines-Practices/dp/0321113586)

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance should not be avoided 'as is'.
Inheritance should be used (and only used) when you want to define / describe an 'is a' relationship.

When an entity 'is not' anotherentity, entity should not inherit from anotherentity.
In such cases, composition should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance helps generalization (which is upcasting in OOP terms), whereas Composition helps behavior definition (Inversion of Control - or Dependency Injection).

One should use whichever grants more benefit; but favoring Composition also makes the code more extend-able. Thus, the code becomes "closed to modification, but open to extension" and thus "HAS-A is better than IS-A".

Kind of like being a car yourself or owning a car (or not?)