# Any reason to prefer static_cast over a chain of implicit conversions?

Tags: c++, casting

Suppose I have a class implementing several interfaces

```
class CMyClass : public IInterface1, public IInterface2 { };
```

and in a member function of that class I need to obtain a `void*` pointer to one of those interfaces (typical situation in [`IUnknown::QueryInterface()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742848/why-exactly-do-i-need-an-explicit-upcast-when-implementing-queryinterface-in-an).

The typical solution is to use a `static_cast` to achieve pointer adjustment:

```
void* pointer = static_cast<IInterface2*>( this );
```

and it is safe in this case if there's no known class inherited from `CMyClass`. But if such class exists:

```
class CDerivedClass : public CUnrelatedClass, public CMyClass {};
```

and I accidentially do

```
void* pointer = static_cast<CDerivedClass*>( this );
```

and `this` is actually a pointer to `CMyClass` instance the compiler won't catch me and the program might run into undefined behavior later - `static_cast` becomes unsafe.

The suggested solution is to use implicit conversion:

```
IInterface2* interfacePointer = this;
void* pointer = interfacePointer;
```

Looks like this will solve both problems - pointer adjustment and risk of invalid downcast.

Are there any problems in the second solution? What could be the reasons to prefer the first one?

Comment: Its interesting that `CMyClass` has knowledge of `CDerivedClass` here... Not impossible, not even a real sign of horrible design, but in the general case, `CMyClass` should not have any knowledge of its descendants. I can imagine having the definitions of both classes in headers and the translation unit where `CMyClass` methods are defined including both, more so in VS with its tendency to advocate precompiled headers... still, food for thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this template:

```
template<class T, class U> T* up_cast(U* p) { return p; }
```

usage:

```
struct B {};
struct C : B {};

int main()
{
  C c;

  void* b = up_cast<B>(&c);
}
```

Note that the '*' is implicit. If you prefer `up_cast<B*>`, adjust the template accordingly.

Comment: That's called "upcast" - base classes are usually drawn at the top, derived at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning to void* is always unsafe. Whichever way you write it you can mess up - assuming that the user is trying to QI for Interface1, then neither of the following will be a warning or error:

```
Interface2* interfacePointer = this;
void* pointer = interfacePointer;
```

or

```
void* pointer = static_cast<Interface2*>( this );
```

Given the tiny risk of accidentally using a static_cast to up cast, in a file that most likely wont even have access to the definition of the derived class, I see a lot of extra effort for very little actual safety.

Comment: "a lot of extra effort" for two lines instead of one seems a little exaggerated claim to me.

Comment: I think you should read effort as effort to read, rather than effort to write.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any reason in not using the latter solution other than the fact that, if somebody else is reading your code it won't communicate immediatly why you are using such a convoluted statement ("why isn't he just using a static_cast?!?"), so it would be better to comment it or make the intent very clear.

Comment: Using one of the template suggestions in the other answers, you can achieve both safety and clearity.

Comment: I feel it stills missing something, but at least it's more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis looks sound to me.  The reason not to use your implicit approach are not compelling:

- slightly more verbose
- leaves variables hanging around
- static_cast<> is arguably more common, therefore more likely to be obvious to other developers, searched for etc.
- in many cases even the declarations of derived classes won't appear before the definition of the base class functions, so there's no potential for this type of error

Answer (score 1):

If you are afraid of doing something by accident with the `static_cast` then I suggest that you wrap the casting/interface pointer obtaining into some template function, e.g. like this:

```
template <typename Interface, typename SourceClass>
void set_if_pointer (void * & p, SourceClass * c)
{
  Interface * ifptr = c;
  p = ifptr;
}
```

Alternatively, use `dynamic_cast` and check for the `NULL` pointer value.

```
template <typename Interface, typename SourceClass>
void set_if_pointer (void * & p, SourceClass * c)
{
  p = dynamic_cast<Interface *>(c);
}
```

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is waste of time (about 2 thousand cycles) and won't spot a dumb mistake until execution passes through that code. Yes, it's better than nothing, but compile-time checks are usually better than equivalent runtime checks.