# What's the use of _ATL_PACKING constant when computing distance from the start of object?

Tags: c++, com, macros, casting, atl

ATL features [a set of macros for so-called COM maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfb1zk2x(v=vs.80).aspx). COM map is a table that associates an interface GUID with an offset that is to be added to `this` pointer to get to the corresponding subobject - the whole stuff works as replacement to [explicit `static_cast` for the upcast inside `IUnknown::QueryInterface()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1742848/57428).

The map entries are built by using `offsetofclass` macro:

```
#define _ATL_PACKING 8
#define offsetofclass(base, derived)\
    ((DWORD_PTR)(static_cast<base*>((derived*)_ATL_PACKING))-_ATL_PACKING)
```

which I'll rewrite as the following pseudocode "function" for readability in this question:

```
derived* derivedPointer = (derived*)_ATL_PACKING;
base* basePointer = static_cast<base*>(derivedPointer);
DWORD_PTR offset = (DWORD_PTR)(basePointer)-_ATL_PACKING;
```

Looks reasonable - it obtains a pointer to an imaginary derived object, then does an explicit `static_cast` to shift the pointer, then computes distance between those imaginary objects.

The question is why is the constant 8 there? Why do we need that constant and why is it chosen to be 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-zero constant is there because the macro does not work with null pointers. We know that the value of a null pointer is a null pointer constant which evaluates to `0`:

> **C++ Standard 4.10/1 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]:**
>
> A null pointer constant is an integral
>   constant expression (5.19) rvalue of
>   integer type that evaluates to zero. A
>   null pointer constant can be converted
>   to a pointer type; the result is the
>   null pointer value of that type and is
>   distinguishable from every other value
>   of pointer to object or pointer to
>   function type....

This is the relevant clause with respect to converting from a derived class to a base class pointer type:

> **C++ Standard 4.10/3 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]:**
>
> An rvalue of type “pointer to cv D,”
>   where D is a class type, can be
>   converted to an rvalue of type
>   “pointer to cv B,” where B is a base
>   class (clause 10) of D. If B is an
>   inaccessible (clause 11) or ambiguous
>   (10.2) base class of D, a program that
>   necessitates this conversion is
>   ill-formed. The result of the
>   conversion is a pointer to the base
>   class sub-object of the derived class
>   object. **The null pointer value is
>   converted to the null pointer value of
>   the destination type.**

Basically null pointers prevent pointer arithmetic from kicking in during a derived-to-base conversion; you will just get another null pointer. The arithmetic is used to "fix" non-null pointers during such conversions so that it points to the proper subobject. The `offsetofclass` macro depends on this arithmetic to determine the offset.

The number `8` used is arbitrary. You could've used any number there like `1` or `4`, as long as it wasn't zero.

Comment: @sharptooth: There's enough information in the class definitions themselves that the compiler can figure out their sizes and their offsets at compile time. The expression in `offsetofclass` macro evaluates to a constant, so the compiler should be able to fold the arithmetic.