# Casting an Object to char* for saving/loading

Tags: c++, class, pointers, casting

I have a small question.

I'm writing a loading/saving function for getting plain geometry data from a saved file.  The objects involved are instanced from classes with a lot of data in them, but they all use just plain old data, and no pointers/allocated memory and the like.

Is it possible to load the file into an allocated char* array, typecast that to, say, Geometry* , and safely expect everything to not get scrambled assuming I did the same reversed thing when saving (typecasting the array to char* and writing it to file)?

If I attempt to access the array when it is pointed to by a char* pointer, or a int*, or any other pointer type, is there any special considerations I need to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to load the file into
>   an allocated char* array, typecast
>   that to, say, Geometry*

It's possible. I've done a similar job. I had used two chained `static_cast` to do this, as:

```
char *buffer;
//..
Geometry *g = static_cast<Geometry *>(static_cast<void*>(buffer));

//reverse
buffer = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(g));
```

Since the two chained `static_cast` looks cumbersome, I've written this function template:

```
template<class To, class From>
To any_cast(From v)
{
    return static_cast<To>(static_cast<void*>(v));
}
```

Then used it as,

```
Geometry *g = any_cast<Geometry *>(buffer);

//reverse
buffer = any_cast<char*>(g);
```

---

See this topic:

[Why do we have reinterpret_cast in C++ when two chained static_cast can do its job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025843/why-do-we-have-reinterpret-cast-in-c-when-two-chained-static-cast-can-do-its-j)

Comment: Oh, thanks!  I always only used the generic "(Geometry*)buffer;" thing.  I'll have to look up how static_cast differs.  But why was the static cast to void* needed..?

Comment: @Clairvoire: That is needed, otherwise it'll not compile!

Answer (score 0):

You can write out an array of POD objects (that don't contain pointers) as bytes and then read them back in.  The casts you propose will do that; you need to use `char*` and not `int*` to avoid problems with type-based alias analysis.  However, you would need to read them in on a system with the same word size, endianness, and struct layout as the machine used to write them out.

Comment: Endianness, I assume that could cause variables with 2 or 4 words to have them reversed?  I didn't think of that, I'm glad you brought that up!

Comment: @Clairvoire: Yes, that can lead to things being reversed.  Different padding and word sizes can also cause problems.  Use a serialization library if you care about those things.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a library for serialization, such as [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)