# C++: can a field object know its "parent" without storing a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

Suppose I have this setup:

```
struct XView;
struct X
{
  ...
  XView  view;
};
```

Type `XView` is only used for this one field; it is internal too, so instantiating it from outside, i.e. using it for anything else is prohibited.

So, assuming *any* object of `XView` type is an `X::view` field, is it possible to find address of `X` from address of `XView`, staying fully within behavior defined by C++ standard *and without type-punning*?  I.e. is it possible to do something like this:

```
void XView::some_function ()
{
  X&  this_x = some_computations_involving (this);
}
```

I can of course store a pointer, so this would become as trivial as `x = *this->parent_x`, but would like to do without one if possible.

**EDIT: Note that I need an answer without type-punning involved, otherwise I'd rather use that "just store a pointer" solution.**

Comment: @JaredC: I know about `offsetof`, but I'm not sure if I can use it in this case without some ugly `reinterpet_cast`.

Comment: Can't you use inheritance for this? Make `XView` a base class of `X` and you won't have to do any casting at all.

Comment: @Insilico: No, I have to be sure that `X x; x.view.do_stuff()` works for compatibility reasons.

Comment: You should've made `view` private and made a `x.get_view()` function. :-) But yeah that does make using inheritance a no-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach is to make `XView` the first member of `X`, then you can do this:

```
void XView::some_function ()
{
   X & this_x = reinterpret_cast<X&>(*this);
}
```

Second approach is to use offset when `XView` is not the first member of the `X`.

Techinically speaking both of these approaches are same if there is no virtuality involved, only that the first approach is a special case (i.e when offset = 0) of the second approach which is the general case.

As for the edit, I think, without casting it is not possible. You have to store the pointer in `XView`, Or maintaining a map (or some other data structures) of pointers.

Comment: Please see edit. When I wrote about "defined behavior" I meant no type-punning as well, but I'm kinda rusty on C++ terminology and don't know if that was enough. Clarified in any case. (And I also have more than one view.)

Comment: *both...approaches are exactly the same* - not quite, using offsetof should cope with a pointer to the virtual dispatch table for X.

Comment: @doublep: Without casting it is not possible. You have to store the pointer in `XView`, or else create map of pointers.

Comment: @Nawaz: that's what I'm afraid of, but maybe I overlooked some solution with `static_cast`, which would be fine.

Comment: @doublep: Actually `reinterpret_cast` in this case is equivalent to a chain of *two* `static_cast`

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't see how.  If you can rewrite your answer using `static_cast`s alone in a way compiler would accept, then that's exactly what I want.

Comment: @doublep: The C++ standard does actually explicitly allow for using `reinterpret_cast` to cast back-and-forth between a pointer to the object and a pointer to its first member, as long as they're both POD. Although in this case I don't see why you can't use inheritance.

Comment: @Insilico: Oh, that's good.  Can you refer to exact paragraph?  I have more than one view, but perhaps I could use it at least for one.

Comment: @doublep: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025843/why-do-we-have-reinterpret-cast-in-c-when-two-chained-static-cast-can-do-its  ... Also, I've seen @Johannes speaking of `reinterpret_cast` being equivalent to a chain of two `static_cast` in such cases, is per the Standard.

Comment: @Nawaz: Thank you. I'll wait if a more generic solution appears (miraculously), else will accept this.

Comment: @doublep: It's section 9.2 paragraph 17, but the caveat is that the objects in question has to be plain old data types.

Comment: @Insilico also the alignment requirements cannot be made stricter in any given cast

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is whether you really need accessing the parent object from child object and not vice-versa.

I would suggest you using some kind of bi-directional linked list or something like this.

Could your code be refactored to be more object-oriented? (and possibly using the inheritance (and calling the parent by using the super::some_function...)

Comment: I just offload part of the interface from the main object to views. And actually I need that for compatibility anyway, so changing interface is out of question.